# Firebase Auth - User not logged in after Firebase sign up and redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

I am creating an account for a user with firebase.  After the account is created, I redirect to the home page, which checks if I am logged in.  Oddly enough, I am not logged in.

**On Create Account Page:**

```
createAccount() {
  firebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((user) => {
    // write some data to database
    firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(user.uid).child('someKey').set(this.state.email).then(function() {
      // send email verification
      user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
        console.log("sent email verification");
        // Go to home page
        this.props.history.push('/home');
      }.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: account created but no verification email sent.");
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this)).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error: while writing to database');
    });
  // catch any error while creating user
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error: while creating account');
  });
}
```

**On Home Page:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (!user) {
      console.log("no user logged in");  
      this.props.history.replace('/login'); // ISSUE: Always redirected to login, even after signup and login
      return
    } else {
      console.log("Woo! User is logged in!");
    }
  }.bind(this))
}
```

Alternative attempts:

- I have tried explicitly logging the user in after signup, but the same result occurs
- replaced `this.createAccount` with `() => this.createAccount` for `onClick` handler (same result)
- used `firebase.auth()` instead of `firebaseAuth()` (same result)

**Does anyone understand why I am not logged in?**

** **EDIT:** **

Below is how I am initializing my app:

```
<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "myproject.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myproject.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXX"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

It may be worth noting: If I sign in with an account that was not just created (or if I wait a while and then sign in to the account I created), there doesn't seem to be an issue with retaining the authorization when redirected.  It seems to be that it's only when I create a new user and then redirect that it loses the logged in user.

Comment: You don't need to bind this everywhere. You are already using arrow functions, so you're binding this anyway. Does the problem occur when you remove all the .bind(this) suffixes?

Comment: @JoshPittman the same problem occurs when remove all remove all the .bind(this) suffixes and use `=>` to pass `this`

Comment: The next question would then be how are you initialising firebase and what are you importing to the examples above. Can you include the code to show how you have initialised firebase? Just put XXX so you don't share your firebase keys.

Comment: @JoshPittman I am initializing my project with `scripts` in my `index.html` file.  I have edited my question to show how I initialised firebase (with the keys all generalized)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same setup and it works fine.

I have my auth state change listener at the top of my router...

```
state = { user: null };

componentDidMount() {
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
      } else {
        this.props.history.push('/login');
      }
   });
 }
```

In Login.js I have a form that connects to a login function similar to yours...

```
login() {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then(res => {
        this.props.history.push('/');
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(error));
  }
```

The only thing that I can think of you gave history.replace, try changing to history.push.