# Firebase Authentication - User object becomes null only after first successful signup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

## The Problem

I am having trouble with firebase authentication - after a User has signed up for the first time, they are authenticated and an instance is built for them on the database.

The application loads the 'Dashboard' (which is authentication protected by a HOC) and the user information perfectly. However, as soon as I try to navigate within the app using 'react-router' the HOC kicks me out as there has been an apparent change in AuthState and the user object is now null.

THIS ONLY OCCURS THE FIRST TIME A USER SIGNS UP. Otherwise, authentication is stable in all other cases.

**I have tried:**
- Explicitly logging the user in after signup, but the same result occurs

*This below question is similar*

[Firebase Auth - User not logged in after Firebase sign up and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49000873/firebase-auth-user-not-logged-in-after-firebase-sign-up-and-redirect?answertab=active#tab-top)

### HOC

```
export default function (ComposedComponent) {
    class Authentication extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();

            this.unsubscribe = null;
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
                if(!user) {
                    history.push("/signin")
                }
            })
        }
        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.unsubscribe();
        }

        render() {
        return ( <ComposedComponent {...this.props} /> )
        }
    }
    return Authentication;
}
```

### Basic Signup Action

```
export function SignUpUser(values) {
    // Wrap inner log with function to give access to dispatch - redux thunk
    return function(dispatch) {
        // Create session
        firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
        // Successful Session Creation
        .then(function(){
            // Sign Up User
            return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
            // Successful SignUp Logic
            .then(function(response){
                // 1) Save uid to redux state for reads and writes
                values.uid = response.user.uid
                dispatch({ type: USER_UID, payload: values.uid })
                dispatch({ type: USER_DETAILS, payload: response.user })
            })
            // Unsuccessful Sign Up
            .catch(function(error){
                dispatch({ type: DISPLAY_ERROR, payload: error }) 
            })

        })
        // Unsuccessful Session Creation
        .catch(function(error){
            dispatch({ type: DISPLAY_ERROR, payload: error }) 
        })
    }
}
```

**Does anyone understand why I am not logged in?**

Is the authentication object in some kind of intermediary state?

Comment: Could you please console.log('response.user.uid', response.user.uid) . I gusee even you do not login and response is null.

Comment: And also console.log(firebase) to see if it does exist

Answer (score 0):

Try to change page route to dashboard or home page by this:
 this.props.history.push('/dahboard');

Comment: Navigation to the dashboard isn't the problem here, the user is redirected using history.push elsewhere in the app. But thank you for your idea!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try these lines, I think you must fix codes and use arrow functions ...

```
export function SignUpUser(values) {
// Wrap inner log with function to give access to dispatch - redux thunk
return function(dispatch) {
    // Create session
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
    // Successful Session Creation
    .then(() =>{
        // Sign Up User
        return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
        // Successful SignUp Logic
        .then((response)=>{
            // 1) Save uid to redux state for reads and writes
            values.uid = response.user.uid
            dispatch({ type: USER_UID, payload: values.uid })
            dispatch({ type: USER_DETAILS, payload: response.user })
        })
        // Unsuccessful Sign Up
        .catch((error)=>{
            dispatch({ type: DISPLAY_ERROR, payload: error }) 
        })

    })
    // Unsuccessful Session Creation
    .catch(function(error){
        dispatch({ type: DISPLAY_ERROR, payload: error }) 
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The problem isn't with this portion of code, it executes correctly and the user is: